# Changes between two hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two hashes with the below format

```
mydetails[x['Id']] = x['Amount']
```

this would contain data like

```
hash1 = {"A"=>"0", "B"=>"1","C"=>"0", "F"=>"1"}
hash2 = {"A"=>"0", "B"=>"3","C"=>"0", "E"=>"1"}
```

I am expecting an output something like:

> Differences in hash: "B, F, E"

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: I am very new to ruby, I tried using Hashdiff diff = HashDiff.diff(hash1, hash2).should . But did not get the result as I expected.

Comment: What does "did not get the result as I expected" mean? What result did you expect? Why did you expect that result? What result did you get? Why is the result you got not the result you expect? How did you get that result? Please, provide an [mcve], along with all error messages and warnings you get, the expected and actual results, the expected and actual behaviors, and a clear problem statement including examples, and specifications of all corner cases, special cases, edge cases, and all rules for how to get the expectecd results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Hash#merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-merge) with a block would do:

```
hash1.merge(hash2) { |k, v1, v2| v1 == v2 ? :equal : [v1, v2] }
     .reject { |_, v| v == :equal }
     .keys
#⇒ ["B", "F", "E"]
```

**Note:** This will work even for a hash containing a value of `:equal` (to address the comment below), because the merge result would contain a value of `[:equal, nil]`, not simply the value `:equal`. However, to simplify the whole thing and avoid confusion, in Ruby 2.4+ you could use Hash#compact like this:

```
hash1.merge(hash2) { |_k, v1, v2| v1 == v2 ? nil : :different }
     .compact.keys
```

Comment: What about `{a: :equal}` and `{}` ? ;)

Answer (score 8):

This solution might be a bit easier to understand :

```
(hash1.keys | hash2.keys).select{ |key| hash1[key] != hash2[key] }
```

[`Array#|`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-7C) returns the set union of 2 arrays.
It's equivalent to :

`(hash1.key + hash2.keys).uniq`

NOTE: If you want to consider that `{}` and `{b: nil}` differ on `:b` even though they return the same value for `:b` key :

```
(hash1.keys | hash2.keys).reject do |key|
  hash1.has_key?(key) &&
  hash2.has_key?(key) &&
  hash1[key] == hash2[key]
end
```

Comment: Fails on `{a: 42}` and `{b: nil}`.

Comment: I'd argue that it's a personal opinion it it's a fail or not. Both hashes agree on the value for key `:b`.

Comment: @mudasobwa : Do you have a concrete example where keys with `nil` value are needed? I feel like a set might be more appropriate.

Comment: I could think of any data, received from 3rd party and operated with `hash.fetch(key, :novalue)`, but this is definitely a contrived example.